# Freebase: How to use the parameter "cursor" with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cursor, freebase

Freebase: (JavaScript) How to use the parameter "cursor" in a query?

In the following query, I tried to put the cursor variable within the service_url adding '& cursor' at the end, but it does not work. Also, I tried to put the property on the var query, but neither works. Finally I put all the variations that I have occurred in the parameters `$.getJSON`, but none has worked for me. Someone be so kind and would suggest me how it is used.

```
var service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread';

var query = [{
  "type": "/music/artist",
  "name": [],
  "limit: 10
}];

var params = {
  "query": JSON.stringify(query)
};

$.getJSON(service_url + "?callback=?", params,  function(response) {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response);
});
```

Comment: So what error do you get? You should probably just follow this example  https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/mql-overview#querying-with-cursor-paging-results

Comment: I don't know what is the sintaxis. Nearly all times I get 400 (Bad Request).

Comment: If I write it this way it works:
var url = service_url + '?query=[{"type":"/music/artist","name":[],"limit":10}]' + '&cursor';

and then:

$.getJSON(url,  function(response) { ... }

Comment: Ok, thanks, I've got it! the call to getJSON, should be written this way:

  $.getJSON(service_url + '?callback=?' + '&cursor', params, function(response) {...}

Comment: Since you found the answer yourself, you probably should post an answer here.

Comment: Thanks GEMI i'm figuring how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of truing different sintaxis I've got the right one:

```
var service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread';

var query = [{
  "type": "/music/artist",
  "name": [],
  "limit: 10
}];

var params = {
  "query": JSON.stringify(query)
};

$.getJSON(service_url + '?callback=?' + '&cursor', params, function(response) {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response);
});
```